# Unable to access Junit in a maven project of eclipse

Tags: java, maven, junit4

I have created a new maven project where I have added dependency for Junit but I'm unable to access `org.junit.*;`. I'm using below `pom.xml` file for the dependency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

It would be great if you can highlight my problem in this code.

Comment: Where you are creating your test class? Under src/test/java?

Comment: I'm trying to create under src/main/java

Comment: Dependencies with scope test are not available under src/main.

Comment: In `src/main/java` only production code is located. Tests have to be located in `src/test/java`....